# Should we mock in cucumber testing while testing java code. Till what extent we should use cucumber?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, cucumber

I am a Java developer. We want to use cucumber testing in our project. We are working mainly on creating APIs. I am good with unit testing and researching about cucumber.
I am thinking about testing persistence methods - CRUD operations as an starter. My questions is that what could be the scenerios in this testing. 
Also should I mock the database by creating tables in the feature file. Should I use mockito with Cucumber to mock call to some other services which connects to database and server. 
What should be the cucumber testing in these scenerios and whats the best way to create framework to use cucumber in our Java API's project.

Also, how to populate models if not using database

Comment: As you're asking a question about what and how to test I think it is probably better of on the Software Engineering Stack Exchange. I think you should work out what your exact problem is before deciding on the tool you use to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO **Gherkin** (the language you write **Cucumber** features in), is good for writing *business readable*, *simple* scenarios.

To answer quickly, I would say that Cucumber is not a good fit for testing methods, if it is what you want to do.

As you can see with the file naming convention, you write `*.feature` files, and I think these files must only contains feature-related descriptions.

However, if you do have ***features*** to test, you have to choose how to test them

- disconnected, can be run quicky by your CI

  - you will have to mock everything that cannot start-up in the build lifecycle
  - and they are solutions to start almost anything using Docker, like [Testcontainers](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java)
- connected to a environment

  - you do not have to mock anything
  - your tests may be slower
  - your tests may break because of the environement (failed deployement, server down, etc.)